# wpf working with events

Tags: wpf, events

I wrote my own control with some buttons and events - that works like a charm. Then I dynamically put this controls as a child in `StackPanel` in other class. How could I in this class (with `StackPanel`) get events from my custom control- I have a public event in my user control - how could I handle it from `StackPanel` class?

I am trying to write something like:

```
 public event EventHandler<ThumbnailEventArgs> ThumbnailClick
    {

        add { AddHandler(ThumbnailClickEventRouted, value); }

        remove { RemoveHandler(ThumbnailClickEventRouted, value); }

    }
    public static RoutedEvent ThumbnailClickEventRouted;
```

To make my `public ThumbnailClick` routed but it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routed event should bubble up so just catch it at the stackpanel.  Be sure when you register your routed event you select RoutingStrategy.Bubble

MainWiindow

```
<StackPanel local:UserControl1.Tap="Grid_Tap" >
    <local:UserControl1 Width="120"></local:UserControl1>
</StackPanel>
```

User control

```
<Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Tap Me</Button>
</Grid>
```

User control code behind

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Create a custom routed event by first registering a RoutedEventID
    // This event uses the bubbling routing strategy
    public static readonly RoutedEvent TapEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Tap", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UserControl1));

    // Provide CLR accessors for the event
    public event RoutedEventHandler Tap
    {
        add { AddHandler(TapEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(TapEvent, value); }
    }

    // This method raises the Tap event
    void RaiseTapEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(UserControl1.TapEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseTapEvent();
    }
}
```

Some of the code in UserControl1 is coped from Microsoft docutments...

Comment: Thank you for your clear solution. I have forgot (due to 12 hours working day ={)set it in XAML element - so there were some bugs/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** You need to [raise the event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent.aspx), also [read the overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx).

---

If your event is public you should be able to subscribe to it from almost anywhere:

In XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:MyControl MyEvent="MyControl_OnMyEvent"/>
```

In the respective `*.xaml.cs`:

```
private void MyControl_OnMyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Handler logic here
}
```

Change the type of the arguments as needed.

If the event is [routed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) up you can also subscribe to it on the `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel local:MyControl.MyEvent="MyControl_OnMyEvent">
```

This allows you to handle the event of all `MyControl` children in one place without adding the handler to every instance.

Comment: I am adding this controls dinamically. I couldnt write <StackPanel> 
    <local:MyControl MyEvent="MyControl_OnMyEvent"/> 
I have <StackPanel x:Name="stackTest" Orientation="Horizontal" /> and all. And there is no property MyEvent at stackpanel

Comment: I am trying to make my event routed but something is not good(

Comment: @PapaJohn: Have you read the overview? Did you raise the event using the respective method (see edit)?

Comment: I am rising it in my radiobutton checked:        private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(ThumbnailClick != null)
            {
                ThumbnailClick(sender, new ThumbnailEventArgs() { ImageSource = this.Tag as ImageSource });
            }

        }

Comment: @PapaJohn: That is not the right way, routed events need to be raised using a method, again, read the links in the edit.